# Emacs gtk keys not working in ubuntu 18.04 with i3

Tags: 18.04, emacs, gtk3, i3-wm

Ubuntu 18.04 with i3 4.15
Note: works with Ubuntu default gnome desktop :-( and is a regression to 16.04.

```
bash> gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme  
'Emacs'
```

and Keyboard & Mouse in `gnome-tweaks` says "ON" for Emacs input
but no luck with C-a - C-e and friends.

This is extremely annoying especially in chrome :-(

Comment: Tried again with 18.04.1 - no success.  It seems that whole gtk keys stuff is not handled properly by i3.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to solves gtk Emacs.
Use i3-gnome!

See https://github.com/csxr/i3-gnome
also
[How can i3 use gnome settings in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062713/how-can-i3-use-gnome-settings-in-ubuntu-18-04)