# How can i3 use gnome settings in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, i3-wm, gnome-settings-daemon

In the past (probably 16.04), simply running `gnome-settings-daemon` allows gnome settings to work in i3 including hidpi settings, media keys, and touchpad preferences.

In Ubuntu 18.04, there is no `gnome-settings-daemon`. This daemon is splitted into several daemons in `/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/` directory. Include `gsd-xsettings`, `gsd-mouse`, etc. However, running these seem to have no effects. I have the lines...

```
exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-xsettings
exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-keyboard
exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-mouse
exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-media-keys
exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-sound
exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper
```

...at the end of my `.config/i3/config`. However, none of my gnome setting take effect in my `i3` session. Do I have to run them in a different way?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting environmental variable XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Gnome and then running the daemon, e.g.

```
 XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Gnome; gsd-xsettings
```

Comment: Where do I set this environment variable?  In my xinitrc?  What if I use gdm to launch i3?

Comment: @MaxCoplan the above line is to be pasted in a terminal, if you want this variable to be set on boot you could set it in .xinitrc, yes. Also, it could be set in a .zshrc/.bashrc or a personal env file.

Comment: Also, I can't find this on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: (can't find gsd-xsettings)

Answer (score 3):

Install gnome-flashback with:

```
apt install -y gnome-flashback
```

Then clone [this](https://github.com/glsorre/i3-gnome) repository

```
git clone https://github.com/glsorre/i3-gnome
```

Install with

```
make install
```

Then reboot and choose `i3 + Gnome` as session.

You should be done.

Comment: Thx. I followed this guide with Ubuntu 19.10 but this does not seem to work anymore. Logging into the GNOME+i3 session responds with an immediate logout and return to GDM. My syslog suggests that something is wrong in /usr/bin/i3-gnome

Comment: I found this i3-gnome fork https://github.com/deuill/i3-gnome-flashback that works for me on Ubuntu 19.10.